# retrieving number precedented by string with regex in python

Tags: python-3.x

I need to extract a year after the string "Jahr" from a sentence and am trying to do this with a regex.

Proved to work on regex101: `(?<=Jahr )[0-9]+`

However in python something must be wrong with the syntax I am using:

```
import re

b = re.match(r"(?<=Jahr )[0-9]+", 'Example Jahr 2007 and more text') 
print(b)
```

should output: 2007

Why does this not work in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`re.match` tries to match the regex from the start of the string.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match):

> If zero or more characters at the **beginning** of string match the
>   regular expression pattern, return a corresponding match object.
>   Return None if the string does not match the pattern; note that this
>   is different from a zero-length match.
>
> Note that even in MULTILINE mode, `re.match()` will only match at the
>   beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line.
>
> **If you want to locate a match anywhere in string, use** `search()` **instead**
>   (see also `search()` vs. `match()`).

In this case, your regex essentially becomes

`^(?<=Jahr )[0-9]+` which of course does not match your string.

If you use `search` or `findall` you will get a result.

```
import re

b = re.findall(r"(?<=Jahr )[0-9]+", 'Example Jahr 2007 and more text')
print(b[0])
# 2007

b = re.search(r"(?<=Jahr )[0-9]+", 'Example Jahr 2007 and more text')
print(b)
# <re.Match object; span=(13, 17), match='2007'>
```